# Meaning of "none wiser"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> His Majesty of Prussia — grim and old —
>
> Sadowa’s King — by needle guns made bold;
>
> With Bismark of the royal conscience, keeper,
>
> In dreams political **none wiser** — deeper.

In this quatrain, what does 'none wiser' mean?

Comment: Nobody was wiser than him.

Comment: https://www.geographyrealm.com/victorian-teenager-created-comical-maps-different-european-countries/

Comment: Whatever it means, those maps are really beautiful

Comment: This (ordinary) use of "none wiser" should not be confused with the idiom [*none the wiser*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/none%20the%20wiser)

Comment: It should probably be considered a poetic expression, rather than common English usage.

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to say that in regards to his political dreams, aspirations or plans none was wiser and none had deeper.